# Remove initial dialog in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: ssms

I'd like to remove the initial "Connect to Server" dialog that pops-up at the startup.

As I prefer using the "Registered Servers" list to access my servers, that dialog is simply annoying.

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2012, if thats important.

Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Startup

At Startup: Open empty Environment.

[image: Startup Options]

It's actually Object Explorer and/or a query window and/or activity monitor that's asking for you to connect - so it has something to work with. All of the options other than "Open empty environment" require some kind of connection to work.

Comment: You could be so blind because there's nothing on the Connect window that indicates it's triggered by the Object Explorer, a window which is still probably on-screen when you enable the above-setting. In other words, this is a poorly-worded feature for what you were asking for. ;-)

Comment: Setting it to empty environment seems not to work for SSMS v17.1 on Win10 Pro at least (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 14.0.17119.0)

Comment: The Startup options were so unintuitive regarding the Connect dialog, but this solution works for SSMS v18.10 on Windows 11. Thank you.